# Optimizing a nested SQL query through (preferably) joins

Tags: sql

I am currently trying to fetch a list of Posts from a database, along with the `likes`, `dislikes` and checking whether the user has liked the post or not.

## What I have tried:

Here's what the first version of the query looked like:

```sql
SELECT
announcements.*, 
users.FIRSTNAME, 
users.LASTNAME,
((SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) FROM likes_posts WHERE POST_ID = announcements.ID) - (SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) FROM dislikes_posts WHERE POST_ID = announcements.ID)) as TLIKES,
(SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) FROM likes_posts WHERE USER_ID = ? AND POST_ID = announcements.ID) AS USER_LIKED,
(SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) FROM dislikes_posts WHERE USER_ID = ? AND POST_ID = announcements.ID) AS USER_DISLIKED FROM announcements LEFT JOIN users ON announcements.OWNER_ID = users.ID
WHERE announcements.CHANNEL = ? AND announcements.ID < ? ORDER BY announcements.ID DESC
```

I have tried optimizing it through serval JOINS, but the results are quite messed up:

```sql
SELECT
announcements.*, 
users.FIRSTNAME, 
users.LASTNAME,
COUNT(likes_posts.USER_ID) AS TLikes,
COUNT(dislikes_posts.USER_ID) AS TDislikes,
UserLiked.ID AS userLiked,
UserDisliked.ID AS userDisliked
FROM announcements
LEFT JOIN likes_posts ON likes_posts.POST_ID = announcements.ID
LEFT JOIN dislikes_posts ON dislikes_posts.POST_ID = announcements.ID
LEFT JOIN likes_posts AS UserLiked ON UserLiked.USER_ID = ?
LEFT JOIN likes_posts AS UserDisliked ON UserDisliked.USER_ID = ?
LEFT JOIN users ON announcements.OWNER_ID = users.ID
WHERE announcements.CHANNEL = ? AND announcements.ID < ? 
GROUP BY announcements.ID
ORDER BY announcements.ID DESC
```

## Queries' results

The first query manages to constantly fetch the correct number of likes and dislikes (example: 5 and 3).
For the second one, however, it constantly fetches a number that is the double of the current `likes` or `dislikes`, whichever is bigger (eg. if there are 5 likes and 6 dislikes, the result would be 16 likes and 16 dislikes)

## Problem

I'm guessing the second query is somehow fetching the `likes_posts` table 2 times, which causes the discrepancy between the likes and dislikes.

Comment: It's actually "fetching" the likes_posts table 3 times because you've told it to in various join clauses.

Comment: Figured that might be the problem, but the problem persists when I'm "fetching" only the likes_posts table and dislikes_posts table each

Comment: count is always bad for the performance create a table post_id likes dislikes and update the counter in a trigger, when you need to run the qoery often

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it, by aggregating the like and dislike counts first, then joining them to the base table.  This way you're only doing the counts once each instead of twice

```
SELECT
    a.*, 
    u.FIRSTNAME, 
    u.LASTNAME,
    coalesce(likes.cnt, 0) - coalesce(dislikes.cnt, 0) as TLIKES,
    coalesce(likes.cnt, 0) AS USER_LIKED,
    coalesce(dislikes.cnt, 0) AS USER_DISLIKED 
FROM 
    announcements a
    LEFT JOIN 
    users u ON a.OWNER_ID = u.ID
    left join 
    (
        select post_id, count(user_id) cnt
        from likes_posts
        group by post_id
    ) likes on likes.post_id = a.id 
    left join
    (
        select post_id, count(user_id) cnt 
        from dislikes_posts 
        group by post_id 
    ) dislikes on dislikes.post_id = a.id
WHERE 
    announcements.CHANNEL = ? AND announcements.ID < ? 
ORDER BY 
    announcements.ID DESC
```